# Apple cannot check it for malicious software (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, macos

Every time I'm trying to run my Flutter app on IOS, I'm getting the above warning:

> “libplist-2.0.3.dylib” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information.

[image]

Why is that happening?

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-x64, locale en-IL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: Just to clarify - This happens when you execute `flutter run` with an iOS target?

Comment: yes running flutter run on ios case this error

Answer (score 0):

Find that file and try to open it. It doesn't matter that it can't be opened but there you can give the mac the permission.
Then go back to your editor and try debugging again, now it will give you the same error, but there will be an option to open that file and the app will run.

Comment: What do you mean be "there will be an option to open". opening from Finder and with context menu gives same dialog for me.  (Ventura 13.6)